# Creating new database on oracle database 11g XE

Tags: 14.04, oracle, database

I installed Oracle Database 11g XE on Ubuntu 14.04 and at the time of installation, I created a default database with a SID `XE`. the thing is I can't get create a new database for a separate project. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle XE is installed as an RPM and supported on RedHat and Oracle Enterprise Linux (for Linux installs). Given that you have done a non-standard install it is virtually impossible to answer your question from what you gave for your installation and configuration. 
On a general level you create new databases (typically) using the Database Creation Assistant (dbca). Follow the prompts.